# Master function that executes subfunctions

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

I have two functions that accept different parametes:

```
def foo(name, age):
    pass
def bar(color, shape):
    pass
```

Now, I have a master function that I want to be able to call with the function I want to execute and it's parameters. Since it's a master function that might call either foo or bar, it's called with only two params (the function to be executed and the parameters for this function.

function is a string telling what function to execute

params will be a dictionary of parameters (like **kwargs)

I can do this to make it work:

```
def master(function, params):
    if function == 'foo':
        foo(params['name'], params['age'])
    elif function == 'bar':
        foo(params['color'], params['shape'])
```

And then I call master like:

```
master('foo',{'name': 'John', 'age': 99})
```

However if master has a lot of subfuntions to call, there's too much conditions and picking the right parameters for each function.

So I basically have two questions:

1) Instead of calling master with the name of the function and then checking this name in a condition, can I directly pass the function to be executed? If so, how do I execute the function then?

Something like calling master like this:

```
master(foo(), {'name': 'John', 'age': 99})
```

2) functions `foo` and `bar` don't have **kwargs, however it would be very convinient if I can call them passing just a dictionary and then they assign to each variable their corresponding value from the dict.

So basically, could I do:

```
params = {'name':'John', 'age':99, 'color':red, 'shape':circle}
foo(params)  # I would like to to this even if foo doesn't have **kwargs
bar(params)  # same for bar
```

So at the end my ideal call of master would be:

```
params = {'name':'John', 'age':99, 'color':red, 'shape':circle}

master(foo(), params) # to execute foo
master(bar(), params) # to execute bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass functions as arguments:

```
def master(func, arguments: dict):
    if func is foo:
        args = arguments["name"], arguments["age"]
    elif func is bar:
        args = arguments["color"], arguments["shape"]

    return func(*args)
```

This can be done even simpler if you don't know the names of the functions' arguments:

```
def master(func, arguments: list):
    return func(*arguments)
```

A much more generic version is the following:

```
def master(function, *positional_arguments, **keyword_arguments):
    function(*positional_arguments, **keyword_arguments)

master(foo, 'John', 56)
master(foo, **{'name': 'John', 'age': 56})
master(foo, name='John', age=56)
master(foo, *['John', 56])
```

Comment: Great answer!! Just one needs to take care that master func is not passed with a func name which doesn't exist or is not in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Function in python are objects, so yes, you can pass them as a parameter (but do not use parenthesis).

```
def master(function, **kwargs):
    function(params, kwargs)
```

Then you call the master:

```
master(foo, name='John', age=99...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function through master function not by passing a function as a parameter inside master, but by passing the definition of the function. Please follow the example below:

```
   def foo(name, age):
      pass

   def bar(color, shape):
      pass
```

Now consider a master function:

Func param will contain the defination of the function by adding parentheses after function name, it will make it to execute.

```
def masterFunc(func, params):
     return func(params)  #  Func param will contain the defination of the function by adding parentheses after function name, it will make it to execute.
```

You will use this master function to execute the passed function defination as below:

```
masterFunc(foo,{a:1}) #Sample execution
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, functions are objects, like everything else. You can pass functions as parameters and execute them very simply.

In your case,

```
 def say_hello(name):
   print "hi ", name

 def say_bye(name, time):
   print name, ", have a good ", time

 say_bye("john", "night")
 john , have a good  night

 def master(fun, **kwargs):
   fun(**kwargs)

 master(say_bye, name='john', time='night')
 john , have a good  night

 params1 = {'name': 'jay', 'time': 'morning'}
 params2 = {'name': 'cole'}

 master(say_hello, **params2)
 hi  cole

 master(say_bye, **params1)
 jay , have a good  morning
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

*function* is a ***first-class object*** in Python and therefore can be assigned to an identifier, passed as an argument or returned by a function.

The unified way where you don't want to bother of keyword args for a particular function - with `inspect.getfullargspec` feature:

```
import inspect

def foo(name, age):
    print(name, age)

def bar(color, shape):
    print(color, shape)

def master(func, params):
    arg_names = inspect.getfullargspec(func).args
    func(**{k:v for k,v in params.items() if k in arg_names})

params = {'name':'John', 'age':99, 'color':'red', 'shape':'circle'}
master(foo, params)
master(bar, params)
```

Sample output:

```
John 99
red circle
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below approach.

#### Code

```py
class A:
    def a(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('A')

    def b(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('B', args, kwargs)

def main(func, *args, **kwargs):
    x = A()
    if hasattr(x, func):
        func = getattr(x, func)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        print('No function name {} defined under class'.format(func))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func = raw_input('Func_name: a/b')
    main(func, (1), {1:1})
```

#### Output

```sh
~/del$ python test.py 
Func_name: a/ba
True
A
~/del$ python test.py 
Func_name: a/bb
True
('B', (1, {1: 1}), {})
~/del$
```

Here, we're using `getattr` function in `__builtin__`.
* First it checks whether there's a function/method named `a` or `b` under the instance of `class A`.
* If yes, then only it will `getattr` from it and execute passing the args and kwargs.
* If somebody passes function name not defined, it will not crash and return saying the needful statement there.

Hope this helps !